# SELECT SUM MySQL query getting java.sql.SQLException: Column 'classifier' not found exception

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm currently trying to calculate the sum of all values from the classifier column from my artifact table. I'm then getting the result from the database and setting it in the "estimate" text field. I'm currently getting the exception java.sql.SQLException: Column 'classifier' not found. I'm hoping someone can help!

```
  @FXML
    void getEstimate(ActionEvent event) {
      try {
          String sql="SELECT SUM(classifier) FROM artifact";
          preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
          resultSet=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
          if(resultSet.next()){
              String sum = resultSet.getString("classifier");
              estimate.setText(sum);
          }
      }

       catch (SQLException ex ) {
          System.out.println(ex);

      } ;

    }
```

Comment: `"SELECT SUM(classifier) AS classifier FROM artifact"`

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your help!

Comment: Or just use the column index in the `ResultSet`: `String sum = resultSet.getString(1);`

Comment: unrelated to fx..